# AS3 - Video complete event

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, video

How to trigger an event if the video is over? I'ld like to show a replay button then.

```
var vid:Video = new Video(480, 270);
vidcont.addChild(vid);

    var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect(null);

    var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
    vid.attachNetStream(ns);

    var listener:Object = new Object();
    listener.onMetaData = function(evt:Object):void {};
    ns.client = listener;

    function  playVideo(e:Event = null) {
    ns.play("sneak.flv");
    }
```

Thanks 
Uli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS` event on your `NetStream` object and check for the "NetStream.Play.Stop" code.

Example:

```
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
```

Then create the handler method:

```
private function netStatusHandler(evt:NetStatusEvent):void {
    if (evt.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {
        // do loop...
    }
}
```

If you need to check more than one code, it's better to use a switch case instead of an if.

Comment: Great thanks! Is it also possible to start and stop the video immediately so the first image of it is showing?

Comment: You can use the NetStream.seek() method to go to a specific time in the movie, maybe you can do that using this method.

Comment: Can you please explain this a little further? Do I just need to add NetStream.seek(1) to my code?